# Matlab Ridge Regression Dimensions

Tags: matlab, regression

Can someone explain the scaling factor in Matlab's ridge regression function? I found a post related to the formula used to scale the values, but I'm not sure why I'm not quite sure how it works. When I set it to 0, I get typical numbers, but am forced to input the X-matrix without the column of 1s for the intercept. If I include the column of ones, the returned b-matrix has one too many rows and it can't be multiplied. On the other hand, when I set the scaling factor to 1, I get completely unreasonable values. Can someone explain what is going on and how I could go about fixing it?

```
b = ridge(Y,X,lambda,0);
size(Y) = 
          444205     1
size(X) = 
          444205     4
size(b) = 
               5     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ridge()` automatically centers and scales `X` (for each feature, subtracts mean, divides by standard deviation), and centers `y`. Let `Xs` denote the centered/scaled version of `X`, `ys` denote the centered version of `y`, and `b` denote the weights returned by `ridge()`.

When the `scaled` flag is set to 1, `b` gives the weights for predicting `ys` from `Xs`; the predicted value of `ys` is given by `Xs * b`. A constant term isn't needed because `Xs` and `ys` are centered.

When the `scaled` flag is set to 0, `b` gives the weights for predicting `y` from `X`. The first element of `b` contains a constant term (which is needed because `X` and `y` have nonzero mean). The predicted value of `y` is given by `X * b(2:end) + b(1)`.

More information about this behavior is given in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ridge.html).

Comment: This explains it. Thank you so much!